# Facebook app missing 3D photo button on LG Velvet 5G

Tags: photos, lg, facebook

I bought the LG Velvet 5G because it has a 5MP depth camera, whuch sounds good for taking 3D photos. All the guides I can find suggest that the 3D photo option should appear in the menu below. But I have looked carefully and I cannot find it.

[image: screenshot of facebook]

Comment: Use the camera app that comes with the device. Does it provide the 3D option? From within Facebook I would use the "Photo/Video" option, as a 3D image is just a regular image (e.g. JPEG) with additional depth information.

Comment: Yes, but as with other phones the camera calls the 3D option "Portrait". Sharing as just "photo" results in a 2D photo.

Comment: Could you go through [Facebook's help center about 3D photos](https://www.facebook.com/help/android-app/414295416095269?helpref=platform_switcher) for troubleshooting first, clarifying if it's the same as the guide you're reading?

Comment: Different Guide. With that guide I get to step 3, and there is a Next button (not Done). I press Next since that is the only thing I can do. At Step 4 there is no "Make 3D" button.

Comment: BTW, the built in Gallery app can convert to 3D (but sharing the image to Facebook still results in 2D).

Comment: Hmm, I think this is going to be more technical on how the Facebook app decides [which photo can be converted to 3D or not](https://www.facebook.com/help/android-app/352960005398344?helpref=related&ref=related&source_cms_id=414295416095269), possibly the "Don't edit your photo" part...

Comment: Well I didn't edit the photo. Has anyone successfully uploaded a 3D photo on an LG Velvet 5G? I have heard people have done it with the LG V60.